# How is attack bonus calculated with a Multiclassed Zen Archer Evangelist with flurry of arrows?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, multi-classing, attack-roll, bonus-type

How is attack bonus calculated with a Multiclassed Zen Archer Evangelist with flurry of arrows?  It seems that I am getting a double bonus with successive levels.  I am outpacing my fellow adventurers.  RAW state:

> ...At 2nd level, the evangelist must choose a class she belonged to before adding the prestige class to be her aligned class. She gains all the class features for this class, essentially adding every evangelist level beyond 1st to her aligned class to determine what class features she gains. She still retains the Hit Dice, base attack bonus, saving throw bonuses, and skill ranks of the prestige class, but gains all other class features of her aligned class as well as those of the evangelist prestige class.

Therefore I take the BAB from evangelist.  So as a Level 5 Evangelist, I have a BAB +3.

I also have 2 previous levels in Inquisitor granting me BAB +1

ALSO  RAW state:

> A monk using flurry treats his BAB from monk levels as equal to his monk level. He still adds BAB from other sources (such as other classes or racial Hit Dice) normally to this total.

So as a Level 7 Monk I have BAB (monk level) 7 (aligned class) 
So my calculations have a 7+3+1=11 - 2 for flurry = +9/+9/+4.  Is that correct??

Build, as-is:

- 2 levels of Inquisitor
- 3 levels of Zen Archer Monk (EML of 7 with Evangelist)
- 5 levels of Evangelist (4 of which also provide Monk Features)

22 Wisdom (+6 Mod, used for Archery via [Zen Archery](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/archetypes/paizo-monk-archetypes/zen-archer/))

Feats

- 1 Steel Soul
- 3 Deadly Aim
- 5 Dwarven Hatred Style, Point Blank Shot (Monk 1)
- 6 Precise Shot (Monk 2)
- 7 Dwarven Seething
- 9 Clustered Shots
- 10 Point-Blank Master (Monk 3)
- Zen Archer: Perfect Strike, Weapon Focus

Comment: Could you please list **all the the different class levels** of your character, along with his **wisdom score** and **feats**? That would help a lot for answering :)

Comment: @FlavienKnuchel the basic issue: evangelist is designed to advance all features of a previous class, but not their BAB.  The monk has a flurry feature, which effectively replaces his BAB under some circumstances.  Advancing this feature allows the evangelist to, in essence, trade in a BAB bonus they weren't getting in the first place.

Comment: level 1-2 Inquisitor, levels 3-5 Monk - Zen Archer, level 6 Evangelist, level 7-10 Evangelist & Zen Archer.  WIS  6 (but I haven't added that to calculations above -since I was just asking about BAB.)  Feats:
1st Steel Soul 3rd Deadly Aim 5th Dwarven Hatred Style 
Zen 1st Bonus Point-Blank Shot  
Zen 1st Perfect Strike attack 
Zen 2nd Bonus Precise Shot  
Zen 2nd Weapon Focus 
Zen 3rd Bonus Point-Blank Master 
7th  Dwarven Seething 
Zen 6th Weapon Specialization
Zen 6th Bonus Improved Precise Shot
9th  Clustered Shots

Comment: So with adding those factors I am hitting w flurry +15/+15/+10  (BAB +9/+9/+4, WIS +6, +2bow, WF +1, DAim -3)

Comment: Rowley, I moved your comments into your post; information in comments is occasionally dumped, but its important information for incoming answers and their context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Your BAB from Inquisitor is +1(.5)
- Your BAB from Monk is +2(.25)
- Your BAB from Evangelist +3(.75)

Your Monk Flurry of Blows allows that

> For the purpose of these attacks, the monk’s base attack bonus from his monk class levels is equal to his monk level. For all other purposes, such as qualifying for a feat or a prestige class, the monk uses his normal base attack bonus.

And your Evangelist allows that

> She gains all the class features for this class, essentially adding every evangelist level beyond 1st to her aligned class to determine what class features she gains.

However! Your Evangelist levels 2-5 should be included *as* Monk levels, giving you 'Full BAB' for those 5 levels, not 1.75 BAB per level. At least, that's what [this post on the message boards](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2r2n8?Evangelist-Alinged-class-Flurry-of-Blows) indicates, with math showing that a Monk 10/Evangelist 10 would have an effective Flurry BAB of 26 if you think the Aligned class stacks with their base BAB.

So your Flurry BAB should be 
 - +1 from Inquisitor
 - +0 from Evangelist
 - +7 from Monk/Evangelist

For a total of +8 (+6 Wisdom +1 Weapon Focus + 2 Bow enhancement + 1 Point Blank Shot(possibly) - 3 Deadly Aim (optional)) for ~ +14 or +15

Comment: I think the question is if they are allowed to use the monk level + evangelist level + bab from inquisitor AND evangelist.

Comment: I read the confusion as 'does my Flurry BAB increase equal to my effective Monk level (7) + Evangelist BAB'. Essentially, every level of Evangelist (except the first) gives 1.5 BAB by that interpretation

Comment: Of course the Inquisitor BAB adds in as normal, it's just the Aligned Class feature that's hinky